# Touchscreen driver that just makes people stop touching my screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchscreen

Context:

- People [keep touching my screen](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54312/how-do-i-get-my-coworkers-to-not-touch-my-computer-screen), leaving fingerprints,
- My laptop has a touchcreen that I don't use.

Is there a program/driver that would for instance turn the whole screen red for 3 seconds every time a touch is detected? I imagine that would deter anyone from touching it again. Other implementations with the same goal are welcome too.

It should run on Ubuntu Linux. Preferably free.

The tool should not be rude, bonus for even improving the mood of the touchers at the same time, for instance by being funny. The point where the screen was touched could be highlighted to make the cause/effect more obvious. A Frozen-themed freezing of the screen starting from that point could be an idea. I would prefer to avoid sounds, in order to not attract attention from neighboring colleagues nor annoy them.

Comment: Or maybe run a program that plays an audio "Don't touch me!!".

Comment: Or says "ouch!!!"

Comment: I'm probably not answering your question but I think such a driver/tool would not solve your problem because every new person who comes to your laptop will not initially know of its existance and will touch your laptop screen. Maybe sticking a note on your laptop saying "dont touch" might be more effective.

Comment: I always considered, that the concept, where you touch the very same surface on which you are looking is silly. If you mean opposite, try to work whole day on 4K 28+" monitors - or go to the gym (same result).

Comment: @Buzz: That answer should probably go to the human interaction version of this question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54312/how-do-i-get-my-coworkers-to-not-touch-my-computer-screen :-)

Comment: I would avoid anything that provides positive feedback. Improving the mood of the person touching it seems like a counterproductive approach. The original idea of blanking the screen red is better, but even that is somewhat interesting. "Hmm what color will it make next?". Black would be better.